# Figure - Page Number overlap

Tags: floats, page-numbering

I am new to `Tex` and not very experienced. Unfortunately, I've got a problem: On one page a figure overlaps the page number. Actually the image is positioned very close to the bottom page border which looks odd.

I'd be really glad if you could help me solving this issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=100mm]{./img0.png}
    \caption[Image 1]{Image 1}
\label{fig:t2-2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=100mm]{./img1.png}
    \caption[Image 2]{Image 2}
\label{fig:t2-2}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your image is too big!. Try `\includegraphics[height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{image}`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your responses! I added a MWE. @YiannisLazarides There are two images on that page, but I do not know how to move one image to the next page. Unfortunately the image has to be this size otherwise it would be unreadable.

Comment: Don't use `[H]` which tells TeX not to move the figure. Also, you might want `\centering` within the `figure` environment rather than the `center` environment which adds additional vertical spacing.

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much! That solved my problem. You should maybe post this as an answer, so that you can get credits for that. Again thank you so much!

Comment: @user38654 OK. Done. Not much of an answer but I'm glad it helped ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want LaTeX to move a figure to another page, if appropriate, do not tell it to try to include the figure HERE! no matter what. That is, omit the `[H]` argument to the `figure` environment or, if you prefer, you can specify other positions in addition to `H` e.g. `Htb` or something. The important point is to let LaTeX move the figure somewhere suitable if there isn't enough space for it. If you don't specify a position, LaTeX will do this by default. If you do specify one, you need to ensure that you allow sufficient flexibility so that LaTeX can lay things out appropriately.